# How to not confuse between 0 and cancel buttom JoptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm trying to make loop as to validate a user imput in java

the user must enter integer between 1 and 12 but if click cancel the JoptionPane Must close

```
   int number = 0;
     boolean condition= false;

   while (!condition) {
        try {
            txt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Entrez num :", "Number",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

            if(txt!=null &&txt!="0" )
            number = Integer.parseInt(txt);

                      if (number <= 1 || number > 12) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Integer must be between 1 and 12");
        }else 
              condition=true;

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have to enter an integer");
        }

   }
```

The problem I'm facing is when the user click on cancel this condition is popping , but I want the Joption pane to close and return to main menu

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Integer must be between 1 and 12");
```

how to not confuse between when the user enter 0 in the box and when he click cancel ?

Much Appreciation,

Bass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) say?

It says:

> Returns: user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input.

So if you get `"0"`, the user entered 0, and if you get `null`, the user cancelled.

Side note: [don't use == to compare strings. Use equals().](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Tip for my self : Consult Javadoc before asking :)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of writing it :

```
 if(txt!=null &&txt!="0" )
{
 if (number <= 1 || number > 12) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Integer must be between 1 and 12");
 else
  number = Integer.parseInt(txt);
}
else ///He hit calcel
condition= true
```